# How to change SQL query so that distinct column values are used as columns names

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
      [NumeroDocumento]
      ,[Nombre]
      , cast(BIT.Fecha as Date) as 'Fecha Bitacora'
      , abs([OPN].KmInicio - [OPN].KmFin) as 'Kms'
  FROM [adm].[Tripulantes] as TRI
  INNER JOIN bit.OperacionesNavegaciones as OPN on OPN.TripulanteId = TRI.Id
  INNER JOIN bit.Bitacora as BIT on BIT.Id = OPN.BitacoraId
```

Which is producing the following output

[image: Current SQL output]

I need to change that SQL so that the ouput is changed to this

[image]

As you can see the name of the person appears once by row and the date field is render as a column for each distinct value

I have tried using PIVOT, which I am very new using the following sintax

```
SELECT TOP 4 
      TRI.NumeroDocumento
      ,[Nombre]

      , cast(BIT.Fecha as Date) as 'Fecha Bitacora'
      , abs([OPN].KmInicio - [OPN].KmFin) as 'Kms'
  FROM [adm].[Tripulantes] as TRI
INNER JOIN bit.OperacionesNavegaciones as OPN on OPN.TripulanteId = TRI.Id
INNER JOIN bit.Bitacora as BIT on BIT.Id = OPN.BitacoraId

      PIVOT 
  (
  max([OPN].KmInicio) for BIT.FECHA in ([2016-01-04], [2016-03-24],[2016-01-25],[2016-03-02])

  ) as bla
```

But I am getting this error when executing

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'bla'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "TRI.NumeroDocumento" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "BIT.Fecha" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "OPN.KmInicio" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "OPN.KmFin" could not be bound.
```

By the way those errors can be fixed using the following sintax

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT 
    TOP 1000 
      TRI.NumeroDocumento
      ,[Nombre]

      , cast(BIT.Fecha as Date) as 'Fecha Bitacora'
      , abs([OPN].KmInicio - [OPN].KmFin) as Kms
  FROM [adm].[Tripulantes] as TRI

INNER JOIN bit.OperacionesNavegaciones as OPN on OPN.TripulanteId = TRI.Id
INNER JOIN bit.Bitacora as BIT on BIT.Id = OPN.BitacoraId
) src
      PIVOT 
  (
  sum(src.Kms) for src.[Fecha Bitacora] in ([2016-01-04], [2016-03-24],[2016-01-25],[2016-03-02])

  ) as bla
```

Comment: Use `pivot`. Simple tutorial is here: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I have updated my question with the PIVOT that I am trying to use and the errors that I get - thank for the tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in a reporting application such as SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). For your information, this operation of converting row data into grouped columns is called *pivoting*, and while SQL Server does do pivoting, it can't do automatic pivoting based on unique values in the result set unless you do all the heavy lifting yourself using dynamic SQL.

Another option is Microsoft Access.

Don't try to turn SQL Server into a UI-level reporting platform. Use tools designed for the job.